# ¿Cómo leer un archivo ncdf4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un archivo denominado `PISCOpd.nc`, y no encuentro el modo de que `python` lo reconozca.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa `scipy.io` te dejo la explicación en el código:

```
from scipy.io import netcdf

#Leemos el archivo poniendo su path y en modo lectura con "r"
archivo = netcdf.NetCDFFile("path/al/fichero.nc",'r')

archivo.variables #tiene varios métodos, este por ejemplo para ver las variables
archivo.close() #para cerrar el archivo
```

Puedes ver más sobre esta función y sus métodos en la [documentación oficial de scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.io.netcdf.netcdf_file.html)

Comment: muchas gracias estimado Rubiales Alberto

Comment: @antoniocisneros, si la respuesta de Alberto te ha ayudado, recuerda aceptarla haciendo click sobre el tilde debajo del número de votos (y por que no darle un +1), eso ayudará a que la misma perdure y sea útil a otros usuarios.